# CodeBlocks wxWidgets-3.2.2.1 compile error

Tags: c++, codeblocks, wxwidgets

### Situation

I am trying to learn a bit of C++ and I am using the IDE Code::Blocks 20.03 32bit (=C::B), wxWidgets-3.2.2.1 and GNU GCC compiler.

I crated a GUI with wxSmith adding wxFrame. Inside it I added some other components (ex: wxSplitterWindows, wxAuiManagers, wxPanes, Checkboxes, textboxes and more).
The following screenshot shows the main tree structure:

[image]

C::B on its own generated the relative code of the GUI and among the other lines of code, into the file **splitter.h**, C::B generated the following function declaration:

```
void Initialize(wxWindow *window);
```

and into the file **dlgMain.cpp** C::B generated the following code:

```
SplitterWindow->Initialize(AuiManager);
```

Into the splitter window components I also created Graphically some AuiManagers. For them the IDE C::B automatically created code like the following, of course changing the variable names for each of them:

```
AuiManager = new wxAuiManager(SplitterWindow, wxAUI_MGR_ALLOW_ACTIVE_PANE|wxAUI_MGR_DEFAULT);
```

Into some of them I've also created some panels and C::B crated the code as follows also changing automatically the var names as it needed:

```
AuiManager->AddPane(Panel3, wxAuiPaneInfo().Name(_T("PaneName3")).DefaultPane().Caption(_("3) Caption of the Pane 3 (Auto Sorted Alphanumerically)")).CaptionVisible().MaximizeButton().CloseButton(false).Position(2).Center().Floatable(false).Movable(false).PaneBorder(false));
AuiManager->Update();
```

The Frame is much more complex of course and has as you can expect multiple files and some thousands lines of total code.

### The problem

When I compile the project the compiler returns a couple of errors like the following for :

```
[filepath]dlgMain.cpp [row number] error: no matching function for call to 'wxSplitterWindow::Initialize(wxAuiManager*&)'
[filepath]splitter.h [row number]  note: candidate: 'void wxSplitterWindow::Initialize(wxWindow*)'
[filepath]splitter.h [row number]  note: no known conversion for argument 1 from 'wxAuiManager*' to 'wxWindow*'
```

The errors are 2 in total one for each of the following lines of code that C::B compiler indicates into the Built Messages Tab page:

```
590: SplitterWindowSxVar->Initialize(AuiManagerSxVar);
1253: SplitterWindowDxVar->Initialize(AuiManagerDxVar);
```

They are contained into the file **dlgMain.cpp** (a file that is part of the project)

they call the row

```
102: void Initialize(wxWindow *window);
```

contained into the file **splitter.h**

[image: C::B Screenshot]

This last file is not part of my project but it is a c++ header file from wxWidgets and it is stored into the following path:

```
C:\wxWidgets-3.2.2.1\include\wx\generic\splitter.h
```

I did not create any of the above code manually: C::B created everything automatically while I inserted components into the Frame using the graphic designer wxSmith.

### What I have tried:

I changed the line

```
void Initialize(wxWindow *window);
```

to

```
void Initialize(wxAuiManager *window);
```

without any success so I returned back to the original code.

I also tried to find the implementation of

```
void Initialize(wxWindow *window);
```

with no success: I can find just the above line that I suppose should be the declaration, but no track of the implementation itself.

I also deleted the row

```
SplitterWindow->Initialize(AuiManager);
```

from the **dlgMain.cpp** file: after the deletion, the project compiles and executes correctly whit no errors, but the line of code I deleted is **regenerated automatically** by C::B as soon as the file is updated or closed and reopened for any reason, so the error shows again right after.

### Some screenshots that I hope can be helpful

[image]
[image]
[image]

The lines I delete are those indicated by the red rectangle on the left sides, where are the row numbers. But C::B recreates them automatically as already described.

### Questions:

1. What is the meaning of the error shown at compile time?
2. Why the line of code that generates the error is regenerated automatically by C::B after I delete it and the project is updated or closed and reopened?
3. Why C::B generates **automatically** code that generates errors when compiling?
4. What do I do to get rid of the error once and for all?

Comment: One question per question, and a solid [mcve] as required here please!

Comment: I was clear enough. You may want to read up further in the  [help], how to make your question better.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I updated the question in some parts and added a screenshot hopping this will be helpful. If it is needed more maybe suggest me what parts I should publish because I am a complete newbie in c++ and I am not able to decide what parts could be important for pointing in the right direction. So I also need to be pointed out to the right direction.

Comment: Please, reduce your app to a minimum (a couple of panes, a AUI, a Splitter). Then copy&paste here it (mostly) all. Also, an image with the GUI you wish is valuable.

Comment: @Ripi2 I uploaded a screenshot of the tree view of the main components I added to the frame/window/dialog. Can that be helpful?

Answer (score 1):

The error you're getting is simple to understand: `wxSplitterWindow::Initialize()` requires a window and you're trying to pass it `wxAuiManager` which is not a window at all, it's something that manages floating/dockable panes inside the window associated with it. It's surprising that C::B allows you to use it as a "component" but this really doesn't make sense and you simply shouldn't do it.

It's a bit harder to suggest what should you actually do instead because it's not clear what would you like to do. Putting AUI panes inside `wxSplitterWindow` doesn't make much sense because AUI allows you to do much more than just resize the windows, so perhaps you just don't need the splitter at all?

Comment: **requires a window and you're trying to pass it wxAuiManager** I agree with it: in fact I tried to modify the function to **void Initialize(wxAuiManager *window);** but it did not work either. It is also surprising the C::B wrote all the code on its own and if I delete the row that calls the **Initialize** function the app gets compiled and executed correctly but when the file is updated, C::B writes back the code that doesn't work... I am afraid that CB is buggy or I really don't know what I am doing. This last one is more probable tho.

Comment: @willywonka, you need to p[ass wxWindow and not wxAuiManager. DO the sketch somewhere on the piece of paper and put it here in the OP.

Comment: @Igor, I just uploaded the tree view into the original question Does it help?

Comment: @willywonka, why do you want wxSplitterWindow? Please check `auidemo` sample to see what AUI is all about.

Comment: @Igor, I want just study how c++, CB and wxWidgets components work for learning purpose for now at least, I hope in the near future to be able to do a N++ plugin to share online with those that could need it.

Comment: @willywonka, what I mean is - you don't need wxSplitter if you want AUI. But you should look at what AUI offer to decide if you want it or you want "regular" GUI design

Comment: @Igor Oh yes sure: I am of course at the same time looking around to understand what I'am dealing with too. For example I have watched yt videos, I have read online about AUI and splitters and wxWidget in general and I also had a look at the Kirix Strata application to better understand the power of wxWidgets. But after all I am just a newbie and I have much to learn yet and I try to effort myself to integrate data from multiple sources to get deeper information. At the same time I try to do some programming homework to develop my skills that are too limited at the moment.

Comment: @Igor I have also noticed an unpleasant handicap about wxWidget tho: my exercise application once compiled in binary form is at the moment less than 2 MB (still not complete and will grow up). But another problem to make it work is that I must put into the same directory (= Debug directory, for now) a library -> wxmsw32ud_gcc_custom.dll which is **318 MB big**... Not good at all: if I intend to make a Npp plugin when I become good enough to, that huge dll file will be a huge problem: usually Npp plugins are in fact from some hundred KB to some MB But this another thing and I'm going Off Topic

Comment: @willywonka, how did you build wxWidgets?

Comment: @Igor, 1) I installed the exe:
"wxWidgets wxMSW-3.2.2.1-Setup.exe"

2) Than by win7 cmd I did:
c:
cd C:\wxWidgets-3.2.2.1\build\msw>

3) Cleaned the directory with:
mingw32-make.exe -f makefile.gcc clean

4) I've compiled the debug mode:
mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc BUILD=debug SHARED=1 MONOLITHIC=1 UNICODE=1 CXXFLAGS=-fno-keep-inline-dllexport

5) Renamed the directory:
ren "C:\wxWidgets-3.2.2.1\lib\gcc_dll" "C:\wxWidgets-3.2.2.1\lib\LibDebugUnicode"

Continues...

Comment: ...Continues...
6) Compiled againg the release mode:
mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc BUILD=release SHARED=1 MONOLITHIC=1 UNICODE=1 CXXFLAGS=-fno-keep-inline-dllexport

7) Renamed the directory:
ren "C:\wxWidgets-3.2.2.1\lib\gcc_dll" "C:\wxWidgets-3.2.2.1\lib\LibReleaseUnicode"

It took a long while for compiling the 2 different modes.

At the end I Configured C::B to use them.

Comment: @willywonka, use `SHARED=0 MONOLITHIC=0`. SHARED option controls whether it build dynamic or static library. MONOLITHIC=1 is used by CodeBlocks developers, bit not end user devs. You can also drop `UNICODE=1` - it is used by default.

Comment: @willywonka, also when you are dealing with wx you first source of info should be samples. Second should be official docs. Then you should look at the wx forum and maybe here. And only after all those you can look at YT, search online and check all other resources.

Comment: @Igor, I 've found the following post on the forum https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?t=940 **Monolithic: all libraries are built into one big library. This makes it a little easier for someone who is new. They won't have to deal with linking problems and finding out what libraries to use. They can just set one library and not think about it again. The downside of this is that your link time goes way up. With non monolithic you will have a bunch of separate libriaries. You have to set the libraries you need, and link times are faster.** ...continue...

Comment: ... Continue... @Igor,  And also I've found here: https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/WxWidgets_Build_Configurations these other infos: **When using makefiles, parameters passed to the make program signify the desired build configuration. For example, the following command will produce a Debug DLL with Unicode support:
mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc MONOLITHIC=1 SHARED=1 UNICODE=1 BUILD=debug** I am not sure what is the best way that fits my own needs: I am a newbie and I am not sure  how to configure the linker in C::B and what library set into C::B linker: so it sounds complicated.

Comment: ... Continues... @Igor:  Maybe it's a task I am not up to yet: as a newbie it seems the C::B needs too much configuration to make a working application. Until now I just did a bit of Javascript HTML and CSS with Notepad++ and it doesn't need all these steps to create a working application: it is much more direct. I am getting a bit discouraged day by day... All seems too complicated...     :'(     But I really would like to learn so thank you for your suggestions: I am compiling the wxW lib as you suggested but I am sure I'll get lost again very soon

Comment: @willywonka, are you in school? I suggest you find some community college, get yourself there and learn the language - C++ starting from the beginning, going up to advance. You should learn the language first before trying to speak. You can't learn them at the same time - you will fail. Then when you finish - you should go and dive into the wxWidgets. But you absolutely have to know at least the basics of C++ (language and how the different build tool operates, what they are doing). It will be really helpful for you and then go into wx.

Comment: @Igor: I just finished the built using the command **mingw32-make.exe -f makefile.gcc BUILD=debug SHARED=0 MONOLITHIC=0 CXXFLAGS=-fno-keep-inline-dllexport**: the process took a long while as in precedence but it did not create any dll file nor a "C:\wxWidgets-3.2.2.1\lib\gcc_dll" directory.

Comment: Web UI development is completely different from the actual development and you need to lern the language you will operate. You don't have to know HTML/JavaScript in order to do Web UI, but you absolutely have to know C++/Python/whatever if you want to do an actual programming. Can't stress this enough. Get a C++ courses from basic to advanced (maybe multiple times if needed) and then come back to wxWidgets.

Comment: @willywonka, thats what all decent programmers do - they learn language first and then started development. I hope you will not be "THAT GUI" ;-) Good luck.

Comment: @willywonka, I mentioned multiple times because C++ is not an easy language - pointers, OOP, smart pointers, templates, etfc. Not everybody can understand those concepts from the first time around.

Comment: @Igor don't worry, I am not offended and your suggestions are very wise.

Comment: @willywonka, I sure hope so ;-) And I also hope you will follow for all of our sakes - yours and ours. ;-)

Comment: @Igor of course: I am integrating news from different sources and I am reading here and there. The best way I feel comfortable with to learn is to put myself into a project and get infos around: this way gives me a purpose to achieve and that way I see my progress because my creativity becomes something real and tangible in the mean time I learn what I need along the way: this helps me to not abandon at first difficulties. For me it is much more involving to see something tangible growing up than make very simple exercises just for learning purposes even if at the beginning I just mess around

Comment: @willywonka, I understand. However going to college means you will not just code. You will compete with your peers for the best possible code. And when you get a group project you will learn from your peers, because they have different experience level. Also keep in mind - babies are born without knowing how to walk. They crawl first on the floor, then on all 4, and then start walking. I'm offering you a way to make your life and life of other people easier. Know the language that you are about to speak then speak.

Comment: And it is hard to explain the pointer, references, all possible C++ smart pointers and all templates, OOP concept to someone,  who never programmed before. Because what you did is a web design and its not programming.

Comment: One more time - know the language and it's rules before attempting to speak it.